# Error with quadratic equation program

Tags: vb.net

I have made a program to solve a quadratic equation, and it works fine except for when the part in the square root is less than 0. When this happens I want it to display that there are no roots. This is the code I am using at the moment.

```
 SquareRoot = System.Math.Sqrt((B ^ 2) - (4 * A * C))

   If SquareRoot < 0 Then
        lblRoot1.Text = "No Root"
        lblRoot2.Text = "No Root"
```

However despite this if I run the program where this is the case, it crashes. How do I fix this? (Please can you keep the answer as simple as possible as I am still a beginner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are checking the wrong thing for negative value. The square root of a negative number is imaginary, and that is the error you get when your code crashes. Instead, move the check to the determinant, like so (this is pseudo-code only):

```
IF (B * B) - (4 * A * C) < 0
    lblRoot1.Text = "No Root"
    lblRoot2.Text = "No Root"

ELSE
    SquareRoot = System.Math.Sqrt((B * B) - (4 * A * C))
```

For convenience you may want to create a variable to hold the determinant calculation like so:

```
Dim D As Integer = (B * B) - (4 * A * C) 'Use appropriate datatype instead of Integer
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use temporary variable:

```
Dim value = (B ^ 2) - (4 * A * C)
If value < 0 Then
  ' error handling
Else
  Dim SquareRoot = System.Math.Sqrt(value)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

When you debug your program, you should see that the exception occurs in line

```
SquareRoot = System.Math.Sqrt((B ^ 2) - (4 * A * C))
```

The reason is that you are not allowed to use a negative input value to Sqrt (there is no "negative" square root, cannot be mathematically) so you need to do something like this:

```
Input = (B ^ 2) - (4 * A * C)
If Input >= 0 Then
    SquareRoot = System.Math.Sqrt(Input)
Else
    lblRoot1.Text = "No Root"
    lblRoot2.Text = "No Root"
```